# MySQL sorting on joined table column extremely slow (temp table)

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, join

I have some tables:

```
object 
person 
project 
[...] (some more tables) 
type
```

The object table has foreign keys to all other tables.

Now I do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM object 
LEFT JOIN person ON (object.person_id = person.id) 
LEFT JOIN project ON (object.project_id = project.id)
LEFT JOIN [...] (all other joins)
LEFT JOIN type ON (object.type_id = type.id)
WHERE object.customer_id = XXX 
ORDER BY object.type_id ASC
LIMIT 25
```

This works perfectly well and fast, even for big resultsets. For example I have 90000 objects and the query takes about 3 seconds. The result ist quite big because the tables have a lot of columns and all of them are fetched. For info: I'm using Symfony with Propel, InnoDB and the "doSelectJoinAll"-function.

But if do a query like (sort by type.name):

```
SELECT * FROM object 
LEFT JOIN person ON (object.person_id = person.id) 
LEFT JOIN project ON (object.project_id = project.id)
LEFT JOIN [...] (all other joins)
LEFT JOIN type ON (object.type_id = type.id)
WHERE object.customer_id = XXX 
ORDER BY type.name ASC
LIMIT 25
```

The query takes about 200 seconds!

EXPLAIN:

```
id  | select_type   | table     | type      | possible_keys | key       | key_len   | ref           | rows      | Extra
1   | SIMPLE    | object    | ref       | object_FI_2   | object_FI_2   | 4     | const         | 164966    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   | SIMPLE    | person    | eq_ref    | PRIMARY   | PRIMARY   | 4         | db.object.person_id   | 1     
1   | SIMPLE    | ...       | eq_ref    | PRIMARY   | PRIMARY   | 4         | db.object...._id  | 1     
1   | SIMPLE    | type      | eq_ref    | PRIMARY   | PRIMARY   | 4         | db.object.type_id     | 1
```

I saw in the processlist, that MySQL is creating a temporary table for such a sorting on a joined table.

Adding an index to type.name didn't improve the performance. There are only about 800 type rows.

I found out that the many joins and the big result is the problem, because if I do a query with just one join like:

```
SELECT * FROM object 
LEFT JOIN type ON (object.type_id = type.id)
WHERE object.customer_id = XXX 
ORDER BY type.name ASC
LIMIT 25
```

it works as fast as expected.

Is there a way to improve such sorting queries on a big resultset with many joined tables? Or is it just a bad habit to sort on a joined table column and this shouldn't be done anyway?

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question with the EXPLAIN results

Comment: ok, I added the explain result for the problematic query

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT` gets in the way of rearranging the order of the tables.  How fast is it without any `LEFT`?  Do you get the same answer?

`LEFT` may be a red herring...  Here's what the optimizer is likely to be doing:

1. Decide what order to do the tables in.  Take into consideration any `WHERE` filtering and any `LEFTs`.  Because of `WHERE object.customer_id = XXX`, `object` is likely to be the best table to start with.
2. Get the rows from `object` that satisfy the `WHERE`.
3. Get the columns needed from the other tables (do the `JOINs`).
4. Sort according to the `ORDER BY` ** see below
5. Deliver the first 25 rows.

** Let's dig deeper into these two:

```
WHERE object.customer_id = XXX ORDER BY object.id
WHERE object.customer_id = XXX ORDER BY virtually-anything-else
```

You have `INDEX(customer_id)`, correct?  And the table is InnoDB, correct?  Well, each secondary index implicitly includes the `PRIMARY KEY`, as if you had said `INDEX(customer_id, id)`.  The optimal index for the first `WHERE + ORDER BY` is precisely that.  It will locate XXX and scan 25 rows, then stop.  You might say that steps 2,4,5 are blended together.

The second `WHERE` just gather all the stuff through step 4.  This could be thousands of rows.  Hence it is likely to be a lot slower.

See also [*article on building optimal indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. We are using Symfony 1.4 and unfortunately the JOIN LEFTs are done automatically by the framework, so I cannot get rid of it.

Comment: And yes, we are using InnoDB, I will add this informations to my question.

Yes I have INDEX(customer_id), as all foreign keys have an index.
I don't understand why a INDEX(customer_id, id) in the object table would help if I sort by type.name?

Comment: You can use the mysql commandline tool to experiment with `SELECTs` to see how fast it is with and without `LEFT`.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause begs for `INDEX(customer_id)` or `INDEX(customer_id, id)` -- which is the same if you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

Comment: The first query can benefit from `INDEX(customer_id, type_id)` because it can do the `WHERE`, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` all in the index.  The second query can't do likewise because `type_id` is in a different table.